# Getting custom attributes that were set outside the class

Tags: c#, attributes, annotations

Suppose I have a class named *Data*.
Another class annotates one of its members, of type *data*, with some attribute.
For example:

```
public class Example{

    [DefaultNameAttribute("default name")]
    public Data Name{get;set}
}
```

What I'm looking for is a way, from within the class *Data*, to retrieve that attribute and the data it contains. I want to be able to write the following code:

```
public class Data{
    private string _name = null;
    public string Name{
        get{
            if (_name != null) return _name;
            return (getDefaultNameFromAnnotation(this));//this is the method I'm looking for
        }
}
```

In other words, I want to be able to give a default value to a specific field using custom attributes specified outside my class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer : You can't, or at least, you should not.

The `DefaultNameAttribute` is applied on a member of `Example` type, which is decorrelated from `Data` type. There could be several types that use `Data` type, and several instances of the `DefaultNameAttribute`. `Example` can even be defined in another assembly, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on how your attribute is used (if it is on a class, property, method, etc...). For example if it is only used on a class you could get all types that are marked with your attribute with the following code:

```
public IEnumerable<Type> GetTypes(Assembly assembly) 
{
    foreach(Type type in assembly.GetTypes()) 
    {
        if (type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DefaultNameAttribute), true).Length > 0) 
        {
            yield return type;
        }
    }
}
```

If it is only used on properties (as your example), then you could nest an additional `foreach` statement that will enumerate all properties for a given type and look for the attribute.